# iterate through all child elements of a table and reset background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iteration

I have a table inside of which are many other tables and rows and cells and other elements. Some child elements have background color. I want to iterate recursively through all children and reset their background-color to white, only if their current background color is #ede7dd.

How do I do this in jQuery or JavaScript? Would anyone implementation be faster over the other?

I am kind of stuck  here:

```
$('.HDRBody *').each(function(){
    // code here
});
```

Here is a screenshot of the DOM:  http://i39.tinypic.com/2pql4i8.jpg

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't. Getting the elements color will probably return hex, rgb or rgba, depending on the browser, so this seems like a lot of work for something that you should probably find another way to do.

Comment: We need a lot more information to help you find a good solution.  How are the background colors being set currently, for example . . . inline style?  Class based CSS?  Positional-based CSS?  Some sample HTML would be helpful too.

Comment: Please check my answer below with a demo. This should work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EwiWUSU/1/edit)**

```
$('.HDRBody *').filter(function() {
var match = '#ede7dd', hexMatch = 'rgb(237, 231, 221)'; // match background-color
return ( $(this).css('background-color') == match 
         || $(this).css('background-color') == hexMatch);
}).css('background-color', 'white');
```

Comment: Now try that in your browser, and add a console log to check the background color returned by css(), I guarantee you it's not HEX unless your browser is ancient.

Comment: Yes, but you can do or.

Comment: I have modified my answer with a demo

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$("div[class^=HDR]")
```

As it will select every single `div` having a class starting with *HDR*. Please be noted it will match the first class, and not any class name.

```
<div class="HDRTest">...</div>
<div class="t1 HDRTest2">...</div>
```

This will get **only** the first div as in the second one its class name doesnt start with *HDR*.

[jQuery Attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

EDIT: If you want to select the `table.HDRBody` use `$("table.HDRBody div[class^=HDR]")`.